# calculate sum of user's orders in drupal commerce

Tags: views, entities, commerce

Is there a solution of calculating a sum of user's orders in drupal commerce (7.41 core) and display them in views? I tried to create a table in view which couldn't show anything except total number of orders but had not user filter. What should I do in order to combine "user" and "drupal commerce"?

Comment: can't  find a proper button.... I upped...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the view **Commerce Backoffice: User orders**.

1. Clone the display users orders.
2. IN advanced settings, set use aggregation : YES
3. remove All fields from the display except **order Total**
4. In order total field aggregation settings, set type = SUM, group a column = Amount

That's it.

Alternatively, if you don't use [Commerce Backoffice module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_backoffice), you can create a view from scratch if you have no user's orders view (I don't remember which default views are provided with Commerce) :

1. Create a view of orders
2. Add a contextual filter Commerce Order:UID
3. Add a field total and repeat steps above

This should be enough. Remain formatting details...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the commerce "Cart" submodule provides this out of the box with the "Shopping Cart" block. Make sure that module is enabled, then visit the views page for that block (/admin/structure/views/view/commerce_cart_block/edit/default) I believe initially they provide the sum in the footer of the view. I changed my view to display the count of the number of products and I got rid of everything else except the view cart and checkout links. I was able to get the count of products by turning on aggregation for the view ( Advanced > Other > Use aggregation:Yes ) and then putting a count on the "(Line items referenced by commerce_line_items)" field and then adding sort with a count "(Line items referenced by commerce_line_items)"

Depending on what you're trying to sum, you make be able to get it via aggregation in Views.