# How do I create a view of all user accounts who have zero orders?

Tags: 7, views, commerce

I would like to create a view of all users and their total Commerce orders particularly including all those who have no orders so that they can be filtered for. I found [a related question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182257/calculate-sum-of-users-orders-in-drupal-commerce) that solves the issue for users who do have orders but it does not include those who have none.

**What I need to see:**

I need a list of users and whether they have ever ordered anything. Order Count is one possible way to show this. A simple yes or no is all fine. Sample below.

```
Filter: none
uid   order_count
0     12
1     5
2     1
3     0
4     0
5     2


Filter: order_count=0
uid   order_count
3     0
4     0
```

Things I have tried:

1. Creating a base view of users and attempting to add a relationship to orders. This relationship is not available to select.
2. Creating a view with base entity commerce_order with a display of type entityreference_filter. Trying to reference this view using an entityreference_filter filter in a base view of users. This did not work because the base entities of those views do not match.

**What is not working:**

Getting a filter based on the **non-existence of a commerce order/order count of zero** into a view of all users.

Comment: Without you telling us what you've tried yourself so far and where exactly you are stuck this question simply is too broad, sorry. Please update your question to follow our [guidelines](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you :)

Comment: The Drupal 7 commerce module does not alter the views data for users to provide a relationship to the order. It only provides relationship handling from the order to the user. You would need to write custom code (implement `hook_views_data_alter()`) to create this view. The commerce_reports module already does this.

Comment: @mradcliffe I would accept your answer regarding the commerce reports module if you posted it.